# npm run script, can't access command line args

Tags: npm, electron, npm-scripts

I'm an electron beginner, and I'm trying to use it to package up a react-based app.  I'm trying to run electron via a script entry in my package.json:

```
"electron-dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . $npm_config_input \"",
```

That will run electron.js (which is what "main" is defined as earlier in the package.json file), but I need to pass in a command line argument.  I've seen references that indicate $npm_config_input will have the argument passed in this way:

```
% npm run electron-dev --input=file.tif
```

But that $npm_config_input doesn't seem to get expanded for me.  electron.js gets the literal string $npm_config_input.  I'm confused why this isn't working.

It seems I could avoid this problem by doing this:

```
% npm run electron-dev -- --input=file.tif
```

But I don't know how to associate the input argument to the second command I'm starting using concurrently.  It would be nice if I could use something like $1 or $npm_config_input in its definition.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

I'm running this on Windows 10 using git bash.  Other things generally work.  I have nodejs 12.16.2 installed.  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer.  In electron.js, I printed process.argv to see if there was anything of use there.  It turns out process.env.npm_config_input contains file.tif when I run this:

```
% npm run electron-dev --input=file.tif
```

That should work for me.  I still don't understand why the other things I read about and tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you almost got it right, just use [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

for instance, create a file named `cmd.js` that looks like this

```js
console.log(process.argv.slice(2));
```

now create a script hook for it by adding the following to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "node cmd.js"
}
```

now you can try it...

```sh
$ npm run foo -- arg1 arg2

> foo@1.0.0 foo /tmp/foo
> node cmd.js "arg1" "arg2"

[ 'arg1', 'arg2' ]
```

Comment: I understand that I can put args after the "--" in the npm command and they'll automatically get passed to the command.  If I do that in this case, though, I need to pass them to the second command I'm running using concurrently.  In my original example, that's where $npm_config_input is.  I don't see any way to do that, though.